# youtube-dl, how to write all subs of a youtube playlist to ONE single file?

Tags: troubleshooting, youtube-dl, video-subtitles

I'm on Fedora 28 OS and have `youtube-dl` version `2019.03.18` and I wanted to download all the subs and *only* the subs of a Crashcourse playlist off of youtube, consisting of 45 videos.

I want all the subs to be written in a single *.txt file so that I can then edit it and print-it-to-pdf format (with `evince`), also applying the appropriate page numbering/header/footer.

I tried the following:

```bsh
youtube-dl --skip-download --write-sub --playlist-items 6-10 <PLAYLIST-URL> >> all-subs.txt
```

This however only wrote the 'verbose' output to `all-subs.txt` and just downloaded the *.vtt format subs (I don't know why `youtube-dl` won't download in any other format, even if told to do so, a glitch still unresolved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `youtube-dl` doesn't support such feature, but you can use `cat` to concatenate all the downloaded files:

```
$ youtube-dl --output '%(autonumber)s.%(ext)s' --skip-download --write-sub 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3_0x6oaDmI'
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading video info webpage
[info] Writing video subtitles to: 00001.en-GB.vtt
[youtube] w3_0x6oaDmI: Downloading webpage
[youtube] w3_0x6oaDmI: Downloading video info webpage
[info] Writing video subtitles to: 00002.en.vtt
```

```
$ cat ./* > all-subs.vtt
```

Note that `%(autonumber)s` is needed to concatenate the files in order. When downloading from playlists, you may use `%(playlist_index)s` instead.

---

> I don't know why `youtube-dl` won't download in any other format, even if told to do so, a glitch still unresolved

While it's possible to request a specific format using the `--sub-format` option, please note that the availability of such format depends on the website. YouTube only offers `ttml` and `vtt` files, as far as I can tell (and I'm able to download subtitles in both formats):

```
$ youtube-dl --list-subs 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY'
...
Available subtitles for -5wpm-gesOY:
Language formats
en-GB    vtt, ttml
ru       vtt, ttml
fr       vtt, ttml
...
```

```
$ youtube-dl --output '%(autonumber)s.%(ext)s' --skip-download --sub-format 'vtt' --write-sub 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY'
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading video info webpage
[info] Writing video subtitles to: 00001.en-GB.vtt
```

```
$ youtube-dl --output '%(autonumber)s.%(ext)s' --skip-download --sub-format 'ttml' --write-sub 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY'
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] -5wpm-gesOY: Downloading video info webpage
[info] Writing video subtitles to: 00001.en-GB.ttml
```

Comment: I'd like to edit out all the time stamped lines, leaving only the transcript. I've tried doing it with `grep` but is there another Linux CLI tool that can shorten the length of the file?